# My PHP treatement file doesn't works

Tags: php, forms

I need a little help. I created a file traitement.php to recover data from my form but I do not receive any message (Form sent ....) when I click the send button.

Fields: name, surname, email, and project objective are required, the rest not.

I use WAMP + sendmail who is well configured to send mail. Another PHP script works.

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['form2_prenom']) && isset($_POST['form2_nom']) && isset($_POST['form2_email']) && isset($_POST['form2_telephone']) && isset($_POST['form2_societe']) && isset($_POST['form2_url']) && isset($_POST['form2_secteur']) && isset($_POST['form2_projet']) && isset($_POST['form2_nature']) && isset($_POST['form2_objectif']) && isset($_POST['form2_cible']) && isset($_POST['form2_delai']) && isset($_POST['form2_budget']) && isset($_POST['form2_cahier']) && isset($_POST['form2_identite']) && isset($_POST['form2_souhaits']) && isset($_POST['form2_exemples']) && isset($_POST['form2_dev']) && isset($_POST['form2_services']) && isset($_POST['choix_contact']) && isset($_POST['choix_moment'])) {
        extract($_POST);
        if(!empty($form2_prenom) && !empty($form2_nom) && !empty($form2_email) && !empty($form2_projet) && !empty($form2_objectif)) {

            $to = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'; // My real email

            $subject = 'Contact from the site';

            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From:' .$form2_prenom. " " .$form2_email. "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Reply-To:'.$form2_email. "\r\n";

            $message = 'Surname : $form2_prenom \n';
            $message .= 'Name : $form2_nom \n';
            $message .= 'Email : $form2_email \n';
            $message .= 'Tel : $form2_telephone \n';
            $message .= 'Company : $form2_societe \n';
            $message .= 'URL : $form2_url \n';
            $message .= 'Sector : $form2_secteur \n';
            $message .= 'Project : $form2_projet \n';
            $message .= 'Nature : $form2_nature \n';
            $message .= 'Purpose : $form2_objectif \n';
            $message .= 'Target : $form2_cible \n';
            $message .= 'Deadline : $form2_delai \n';
            $message .= 'Budget : $form2_budget \n';
            $message .= 'Specifications : $form2_cahier \n';
            $message .= 'Identity : $form2_identite \n';
            $message .= 'Wishes : $form2_souhaits \n';
            $message .= 'Examples : $form2_exemples \n';
            $message .= 'Development : $form2_dev \n';
            $message .= 'Services : $form2_services \n';
            $message .= 'To contact : $choix_contact \n';
            $message .= 'The : $choix_moment \n';

            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                echo "The form has been sent";
            } else {
                echo "The form has not been sent";
            }

        } else {
            echo "You have not filled in all the fields";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: please post more info about the underlying OS and setup of your project, could be a configuration.

Comment: Ok I updated my post : I use WAMP + sendmail who is well configured to send mail. Another PHP script works.

Comment: As Rahul said, use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) to do this - your script is vulnerable to header injection attacks and will probably result in incorrectly encoded messages as it's doing no filtering or formatting. Email is not simple at all!

Answer (score 1):

First Convert All your lines as below:

```
$message = 'Prénom : $form2_prenom \n';
```

To:

```
$message = "Prénom : $form2_prenom \n";
```

Or:

```
$message = 'Prénom : '.$form2_prenom.' \n';
```

Second: Use phpMailer class to send mails. Visit: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Hi, thank you. I use Wamp with sendmail and that's work with another PHP file

Answer (score 0):

Sending e-mails from a script requires your server to be correctly configured. Check [this](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm) out for further information.

Comment: I use WAMP + sendmail who is well configured to send mail. Another PHP script works.